# Just a semicolon in a C function body.. how is it used? (function called 'prefetch' in linux)

Tags: c, linux, list, gcc

In linux include/linux/list.h, I see this function.

```
static inline void prefetch(const void *x) {;}
```

How is it used?
This function `prefetch` is used for example when defining a macro like this.

```
#define list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)              \
    for (pos = list_entry((head)->next, typeof(*pos), member);  \
         prefetch(pos->member.next), &pos->member != (head);    \
         pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member))
```

Comment: The semicolon terminates an expression – in this case an empty one (just like when writing an endless loop via `for(;;)`, only that the semicolons are mandatory there)`. Such an empty expression does nothing, so you could just drop the semicolon without changing functionality...

Comment: *'I see this macro'* <-> *'This function'* Well, it's the latter, obviously, a function ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks. and changed macro -> function. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does what it says - it prefetches.

Well, technically, it *fetches*, but since you call it on node N+1 as you're working with node N, you have pre-fetched N+1 so that it is already fetched when you are done working on node N.

The reason is, if you go from node to node doing your work, you get a pause in between each iteration of the loop body as you fetch the next node from RAM.

If you were working on a linear array of objects size 10, the hardware cache prefetcher would notice that your access pattern is N, N+10, N+20, N+30... and would start caching N+X*10 before you asked for them. This is a *significant* speed advantage of arrays.

You cannot do this for linked lists - they are not predictably laid out in memory, you need node N to find the address of node N+1

But you can help a little - when you have fetched N, before finishing your work on N, use N+1 for *something*, then finish work on N.

Once you have finished your work with N, hopefully N+1 is already in cache (or at least, the process of fetching it has already started).

What "something" to use N+1 for? Well, nothing. So `{;}`, which does nothing.

You could also `{}`, or `{;;;;}`. My guess is, if the body was just `{}`, you might think it was a mistake, or maybe some compiler gives a warning on empty function bodies. A semicolon shows that you *have* written a function body, you didn't forget, it's just that the body does nothing.

**EDIT**

I should clarify here: I am *guessing* why the function is as it is. I have never seen it before. The information about how caching works for arrays (and *doesn't* work naively for linked lists) is correct, but the intricacies of how to prefetch anyway might be wrong. I wouldn't be too certain this actually *works*, but I'm certain this is what the writer hoped to accomplish.

**EDIT 2x**

Which headers are you looking in?

I am looking through

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/list.h?h=v6.3

and I don't see that function. The `list_for_each_entry` macro doesn't use it, either:

```
/**
 * list_for_each_entry  -   iterate over list of given type
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop cursor.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_head within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)              \
    for (pos = list_first_entry(head, typeof(*pos), member);    \
         !list_entry_is_head(pos, head, member);            \
         pos = list_next_entry(pos, member))
```

Comment: *Does* it actually prefetch? Nothing prevents the compiler from eliding the call (and the corresponding load of the parameter), and I currently don't see why the compiler would ever *not* remove the call. Is this code written purely to target non-optimising compilers?

Comment: @KonradRudolph See the edit - I'm not sure this *works*, I'm just sure this is what the author *hoped would happen*. That said, if it's in a linux header, I'd sure hope *they* knew, and had tested.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree, this looks like the average embarrassing Linux trash code that won't work at all unless you compile with _very_ specific settings...

Comment: That seems to be an OK guess for why the function is _called_ that, slight problem here being that no modern compiler is going to emit any code for calling an empty function in optimised builds.

Comment: Yeah see edit 2 - it isn't in linux any longer, I don't know what linux headers OP had.

Comment: Yeah I looked at Github too and couldn't find it either. I guess someone came along and say "hey lets remove this function which does nothing". How it could pass code review in the first place is a mystery.

Comment: Maybe it did something in 1991, we shall never know unless OP shares what version headers those are and get an opportunity to find the diff

Comment: Compilers had lousy support for optimization in general back then, including inlining, which wasn't even part of the standard. I'm not sure if gcc `typeof` even existed. I don't think the code is that old.

Comment: @SRNissen They (prefetch in list macros and `{;}` in prefetch.h stubs) exist in the ancient kernel 2.6.x. Likely, OP question is inspired by old LK book/course

Comment: Anyway, I think it is just a code style preference of the author of that line. There are still five such places in 5.10.112, in `do {;} while`  and static inlune functions.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer and discussions. That code was from u-boot.v2022.07.  It seems like mips arch has a special prefetch code, so might help in mips only. See https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/v2022.07/source/arch/mips/include/asm/processor.h#L121

Answer (score 3):

An empty `;` on a line of its own is used for self-documenting purposes. For example you way write

```
for(int i=0; i<something(); i++)
  ;
```

In which case the semicolon means "For sure I want this loop body to do nothing". As opposed to badly written code such as

```
for(int i=0; i<something(); i++);
```

Which means "either I want this loop body to do nothing or maybe I just slipped on the keyword and typed a semicolon as a C programmer knee-jerk reaction when finishing a line".

*However*, that same self-documenting effect can also be achieved by an empty `{}`.

Thus `{;}` is superfluous, they could as well have written `{}`. Either way it doesn't affect the machine code or program behavior.

---

> How is it used?

It isn't used. It will get optimized out. The only way to prevent that would be to use `volatile` which mismatches with the function, or to compile with optimizations disabled, which is quackery.

Cache pre-fetching with some typical linked list built on fragmented nodes allocated dynamically won't work, why linked lists like that are avoided. It is possible to implement linked lists pointing at contiguous memory allocated by an array however.

Maybe this code was an attempt at something like that, in which case I suppose that "touching" a memory cell in advance could lead to some micro-optimization, but only if a lot of contiguous access at that memory will happen next - otherwise it is an anti-optimization touching the same memory twice, needlessly.

More likely, the programmer didn't quite know what they were doing.

Answer (score 1):

That semicolon does absolutely nothing. You can safely remove it.

(You can also add more semicolons if you want)

Comment: if it does nothing, why is the function called there?  I guess by calling that function, the `pos->member.next` is used as an argument of a function(which does nothing) and goes into stack? giving it a prefetched effect?.. something like that..

Comment: @ChanKim Any decent compiler will remove the function from the machine code. It is a no-op, it will not have an effect on pre-fetch caching. In fact I would be surprised if not the whole line `prefetch(pos->member.next), &pos->member != (head); ` is removed. Both operands of the comma operators do nothing and have no side effects.

Comment: @Lundin `&pos->member != (head)` is the loop condition, unless it's statically false/true it won't be elided.

Comment: yes, `&pos->member != (head)` is the loop end condition.